# How to use value of a string to refer to variables?

Tags: ruby

Some programmer made a method that gets lots of arguements like this:

```
def age_entry(age_1, age_2, age_3, age_4, age_5, age_6, age_7, age_8)
end
```

They could pass an array but simply they didn't. I love automation and hate to repeatedly add these variables to and array like this

```
ages = [age_1, age_2, age_3 ,..., age_8]
```

I would like to use metaprogramming or other ways to loop with a for or each methods to add them variables to an array like this:

```
(1..8).each do |index| do
   ages << "age_" + index #value of age_[index] get saved to ages
end
```

P.S. I know I can use copy and paste but this is only for doing automation stuff with Ruby.

Comment: you mean `age_entry(*(1..8))`?

Answer (score 3):

"Some programmer" should remember that you can pass in arrays. This sort of method signature is really obnoxious to work with for a multitude of reasons, some of them you've already discovered.

One way to refactor this method and preserve functionality is to just take in *varargs*:

```
def age_entry(*ages)
end
```

Now those values are put in an array for you but you can call the method the same way as before. As a plus you can specify more or fewer entries.

Variables with names like `x1`, `x2` and so on are violations of the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) and are a sign you need to think about the problem differently.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm just working with what was specified and the code there has these generic sequence-type variables, plus the question includes questions on adding up arbitrary numeric references to them. If these really are different, they should be labelled accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need any metaprogramming here. Just splat them:

```
ages = [age_1, age_2, age_3 ,..., age_8]
#         ⇓ HERE
age_entry(*ages)
```

---

If you want to collect `age_(1..8)` into the array, assuming all local vars are defined, use [`Kernel#binding`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-binding):

```
b = binding
ages = (1..8).map { |i| b.local_variable_get("age_#{i}") }
```

Comment: Redefining the signature is the way to go, but if you're stuck with the second approach (for some reason), you can make it a little better with `method(__method__).arity` instead of the hard-coded 8.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the method is as follows.

```
def oldest(age_bill, age_barb, age_trixie)
  puts "Barb is #{age_barb} years old"
  [age_bill, age_barb, age_trixie].max
end

oldest(35, 97, 29)
  #=> 97
```

As well as the calculation in the penultimate line  (which the OP wishes to avoid), this method requires knowledge of an individual method argument (`age_barb`). The following is one way to accomplishing both requirements.

```
def oldest(age_bill, age_barb, age_trixie)
  puts "Barb is #{age_barb} years old"
  b = binding
  args = method(__method__).parameters.map { |arg| b.local_variable_get(arg[1]) }
  args.max
end
  #=> 97
Barb is 97 years old
```

Here

```
args
  #=> [35, 97, 29]
```

Comment: This is the opposite of @mudasobwa's answer. He replaces the method's arguments with `*args` and then extracts the individual arguments as needed. I leave the individual arguments as is, and construct an array of their values.

Comment: well since you went all meta here why not `b = binding and b.local_variables.lazy.select(&method(__method__).parameters.map(&:last).method(:include?)).map(&b.method(:local_variable_get)).max` :)